# Are there any Bitcoin wallets with native I2P integration?

Tags: wallet, network, i2p

Tor usage seems to be fairly common with Bitcoin, but I have heard less about efforts of integrating with the I2P efforts.

Tor and I2P both have their pros and cons, but I am curious to here about what I2P efforts have been made to this point and why more attention has so far focused on tor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C++ may be viewed by some as more suitable for Bitcoin use than Java which I2P currently heavily relies upon

https://github.com/monero-project/kovri

Kovri:

1. To cover, veil, wrap (Esperanto).
2. A secure, private, untraceable C++ implementation of the I2P anonymous network.

Once complete this project should ease of integrating Bitcoin in both a private and secure manner.

Answer (score 2):

As of now, there is no such wallet. But there is [bounty for it](https://geti2p.net/en/get-involved/bounties)

More information [here](https://geti2p.net/en/get-involved/bounties/btc-client)

Answer (score 2):

Since 2021, Bitcoin Core supports finding and connecting to other nodes over I2P.

See the documentation for that feature: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/i2p.md